# Angular 2.0 BETA - HTTP Request and displaying its attributes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

We are having issues with displaying fetched data which is mapped to an interface.
There are these three files called:

- `teacher.service.ts`
- `teacher.component.ts`
- `teacher.ts`

We fetched a normal javascript object but we can't figure out how to display it in the template. We tried to display with `{{teacher.firstname}}` **-> failed** and with `{{test.firstname}}` **-> succeeded**. `test` is a javascript object made by hand and has the same properties(firstname, lastname) like the interface has.

Here are the Test-Results + Error-Messages:

[image]

Here is some code:

```js
// teacher.ts 

export interface Teacher {
    id: number,
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string,
    schools: string[],
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
}
```

```js
// teacher.service.ts

import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, Request, RequestOptions, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Teacher} from '../interfaces/teacher';

@Injectable()
export class TeacherService {

    public constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    public searchTeacher(name:string) {
        if (name.length >= 2) {
            return this.http.get('http://localhost/XXXX/teacher/search/' + name).map(res => res.json());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public getTeacher(id:string) {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/XXXX/teacher/' + id)
            .map(res => <Teacher> res.json());
    }

}
```

```js
// teacher.component.ts

import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

import {Router, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {TeacherService} from '../services/teacher.service';
import {Teacher} from '../interfaces/teacher';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    template: '<h1>{{teacher.firstname}}</h1>' +    // i can use {{t.firstname}} but i can't use {{teacher.firstname}}
    '<input type="button" (click)="log()">',
    providers: [TeacherService],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class TeacherComponent implements OnInit{
    public teacher : Teacher;
    public name : string;

    public test = {firstname: "Horst", lastname: "peter"}; // Test Object equals normal json-object

    constructor(private _routeParams:RouteParams, private _teacherService:TeacherService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
        return this._teacherService.getTeacher(id).subscribe( // fetch the things from server
            data => this.teacher = data,
            err => alert(err));
    }

    private log(){  // log function with a simple click event
        console.log(this.teacher);
        console.log(this.test);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [The Elvis Operator ( ?. ) and null property paths](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to the `test` property synchronously, but you are assigning a value to `teacher` asynchrounously. So The first time angular tries to access the `firstname` property of `teacher`, `teacher` is still undefined, that's why you get the error with one but not the other. The following are some solutions for this:

1- Use the elvis operator like @Eric mentioned:

`template: '<h1>{{teacher?.firstname}}</h1>'`

2- Arguably better, don't even try to render the component until you actually have a value for teacher:

`template: '<h1 *ngIf="teacher">{{teacher.firstname}}</h1>'`

Comment: Thank u very much, this helped me really out!

Comment: np, I'm glad it did =)

Comment: I have been unsuccessful in getting `async` to work with an object.  E.g., `{{ (teacher | async).firstname }}` doesn't work.  I would be interested to learn about a  variation that does work, if you find one.

Comment: I've just used it in the form: `<option *ngFor="#city of cities | async">` and it works fine for me, if I run into an scenario where I need it like this example and make it work I'll let you know, but probably I would just go with the second approach.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I just tried this: `{{ (client | async).city }}` and it worked just fine for me. client comes from: `public client:Observable<Client>;`

Comment: @Langley can u post a full example maybe? i can't get it to work either. The `teacher:Observable<Teacher>;` contains the observable, but the `| async` pipe does not display it.

Comment: How are you creating and solving the observable?

Comment: **In my Service:** `return this.http.get('http://localhost/setzen5_api/teacher/' + id).map(res => <Teacher> res.json());`

Comment: And how do you asign it to your teacher variable in your component?

Comment: @Langley, that plunker doesn't "qualify" because there is no async -- the value is set before the view first renders.  If you change your constructor to more closely mimic an async operation, it doesn't work:  `setTimeout(() => { this.person = Observable.of({name:"Guy"}); }, 50)`

Comment: @MarkRajcok All Obervables are async. Its like returning a Promise at the same time you are solving it.

Comment: Why doesn't [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bcKFvHjxFkZXLODSaaia?p=preview) work then?

Comment: Must be because "the value is set before the view first renders" like you said. The fact that it resolved before the rendering doesn't mean is not async though. Glad that you showed a running example with the issue you guys are having, I'll update if I find anything on it.

Comment: Like @MarkRajcok said option 3 doesn't seem quite right when working with objects instead of arrays, at least not with the current documentation. I'll remove that option from the answer until a decent example comes up.